# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wmi'

Tags: python, wmi, exe

I created executable using Pyinstaller and run it on another computer (Windows 7), but it didn’t work, I got this error. Executable doesn't run on my computer too.

If I run my code using Pycharm - it works. Tell please what I have to do to solve this problem.

Here's my code

```
print('Press ENTER!')
begin = input('')
import pyodbc
import datetime
import wmi

ip = "192.168.18.34"
username = "admin"
password = "xxxxxx"
from socket import *
try:
    print("Establishing connection to %s" % ip)
    connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password)
    print("Connection established")
except wmi.x_wmi:
    print("Your Username and Password of "+getfqdn(ip)+" are wrong.")


connStr = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};'
                         r'DBQ=\\192.168.18.34\Topwin\DatabaseServer.mdb;'
                         r'PWD=01234;')
cursor = connStr.cursor()

created = format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
modified = format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
ArticleID = 123456789
job_pos = ArticleID
cursor.execute("SELECT [(1-2) WireID] FROM leadsets WHERE ArticleID=15")
print('WireID:', cursor.fetchall()[0][0])

connStr.commit()
cursor.close()
connStr.close()


print('==========')
print('Well done!')
```

Comment: I use 32-bit Python 3.7

Comment: please share sample code you are running and traceback of exception.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem earlier, I had to generate a new main.spec file with following command and add your specific options like version file or icon, upx etc (In my case I added --noupx to both, don't know if it has an impact)

```
pyinstaller -F main.py
```

Then I was able to generate my actual executable as usual

```
pyinstaller main.spec
```